# Laravel Many to Many pivot attach error: "no such table: lists"

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, many-to-many

I'm fairly now to using `Pivot` tables, and `Many to Many` relations overall, so hopefully I can learn what the issue.

I have a `many to many` relation between `beers` and `beer lists`, and I have a custom `pivot` table:

```php
Schema::create('beer_list_pivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('beer_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('list_id')->constrained();
});
```

And the relations are looking like this:

##### `BeerList` Model:

```php
public function beer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Beer::class, 'beer_list_pivot', 'beer_id', 'list_id');
}
```

##### `Beer` Model:

```php
public function list()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BeerList::class, 'beer_list_pivot', 'list_id', 'beer_id');
}
```

The `attach` method is used like this:

```php
public function addItem(Request $request, $id)
{
    $beerId = $request->beer;
    $list = BeerList::findOrFail($id);

    $list->beer()->attach($beerId);

    return redirect("/list/" . $list->id);
}
```

This is returning the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: main.lists (SQL: insert into "beer_list_pivot" ("beer_id", "list_id") values (1, 1))

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it says `lists` table not found

try this

```
Schema::create('beer_list_pivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->foreignId('beer_id')->constrained();
     $table->foreignId('list_id')->constrained('beer_lists'); // <= here put your table name
});
```

and refresh migration

Comment: Seems to have done it, thanks! I'm guessing it got confused somehow since I had similar names for the tables

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are new to using `pivot` tables, so let me share some super small tips so you have less errors next time:

1. Try to stick to the [Laravel standard table naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) as much as possible, so you reduce code declaration and possible misses in declaring stuff.
2. You should be safe to remove all definitions for each relation (remove any parameter after table definition).
3. Try to add `$table->timestamps();` to your tables as much as possible, because you will be able to debug anything if you have a `created_at` and `updated_at` column.
4. You can take advantage of [implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) in your controllers.

So, only for tip `1`, your final code could be like this (if you follow standards):

##### Migration

```php
Schema::create('beer_beer_list', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('beer_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('list_id')->constrained();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### `BeerList` Model

```php
public function beer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Beer::class);
}
```

##### `Beer` Model

```php
public function list()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BeerList::class);
}
```

So, for tip `4`:

```php
public function addItem(Request $request, BeerList $list)
{
    $beerId = $request->beer;

    $list->beer()->attach($beerId);

    return redirect("/list/" . $list->id);
}
```

And your route should be something like:

```php
Route::post('/beer/{list}', [BeerListController::class, 'addItem']);
```

The most important thing for this to work is that `{list}` or whatever `{slug}` you write, must match `BeerList $list` or `BeerList $slug` (variable name) and also you have to type hint it. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) explains it very well.

Comment: whenever use `$table->timestamps();` you have to add timestamp function after return belongstomany `return $this->belongsToMany(BeerList::class)->timestamp();` like this